# How do I run multiple instances of my Powershell function in parallel?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, parallel-processing, streaming

Below is my function present in file `streamMonitor.ps1`.

```
function streamMonitor {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
      [string]$directoryPath,
      [string]$scriptToRestartPath
    )

    while ($true) {
        Write-Host "Monitoring directory: $directoryPath"
        Write-Host "Script to restart: $scriptToRestartPath"

        # Get the current time
        $currentTime = Get-Date

        # Get the latest creation time of any file in the directory
        $latestCreationTime = Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryPath -Recurse |
          Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
            Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending |
              Select-Object -First 1 |
                ForEach-Object { $_.CreationTime }

        # Ensure $latestCreationTime is not $null
        if ($null -eq $latestCreationTime) {
            Write-Host "No files found in the directory."
            return
        }

        # Check if the latest write time is within the last 30 seconds
        $timeDifference = New-TimeSpan -Start $latestCreationTime -End $currentTime
        if ($timeDifference.TotalSeconds -gt 30) {

            # No changes in the last 30 seconds, restart the specified script
            Write-Host "No changes detected within the last 30 seconds. Restarting script..."
            Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c `"$scriptToRestartPath`"" -NoNewWindow
        } else {
            Write-Host "Changes detected within the last 30 seconds. No action taken."
        }

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
        continue
    }
}
```

My streamMonitor function works fine, so I'm confused what the issue is.

A different file called `invokingStream.ps1`, where I would like to call multiple instances of the function.

What do I need to change in order to get these jobs to run in parallel?

When I run this file, nothing happens, it just completes the process. However with the function it is calling, it should run indefinitely.

I am running PS 5.1

```
#Invoking Functions in Parallel
$job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
    . C:\pathto\streamMonitor.ps1
    streamMonitor -directoryPath "C:\pathto\stream1" -scriptToRestartPath "C:\pathto\stream1.bat"
}

$job2 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
    . C:\pathto\streamMonitor.ps1
    streamMonitor -directoryPath "C:\pathto\stream2" -scriptToRestartPath "C:\pathto\stream2.bat"
}

$job3 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
    . C:\pathto\streamMonitor.ps1
    streamMonitor -directoryPath "C:\pathto\stream3" -scriptToRestartPath "C:\pathto\stream3.bat"
}
```

Comment: you're never waiting for the jobs or blocking so the jobs end as soon as the script that invokes them ends. `$job1, $job2, $job3 | Wait-Job`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you're missing in your code is blocking the thread that starts the jobs, otherwise, your script ends right after invoking them and in consequence the jobs also end. You can use `Receive-Job -Wait` for this, it also allows you to get back the `Write-Host` output to your main thread.

```bash
$streamMonitor = @(
    @{
        directoryPath       = 'C:\pathto\stream2'
        scriptToRestartPath = 'C:\pathto\stream2.bat'
    }
    @{
        directoryPath       = 'C:\pathto\stream3'
        scriptToRestartPath = 'C:\pathto\stream3.bat'
    }
    @{
        directoryPath       = 'C:\pathto\stream1'
        scriptToRestartPath = 'C:\pathto\stream1.bat'
    }
)

$streamMonitor | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Job {
        . C:\pathto\streamMonitor.ps1
        streamMonitor @using:_
    }
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to almost do the trick however I am getting this error message: [localhost] There is an error processing data from the background process. Error reported: Cannot process an 
element with node type "Text". Only Element and EndElement node types are supported..
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2102,PSSessionStateBroken

Comment: @LukeLopez totally unrelated to the question being asked

Comment: Yes you're right!